# open on FIFO (named pipe) freezes - ignores SIGINT, SIGTERM

Tags: c++, linux, signals, named-pipes, freeze

I'm using named pipes to communicate between forked processes. Each process handles `SIGINT` and `SIGTERM` and then closes its end of the pipe and cleans up.

If the signal happens right when I fork a process, the process then hangs while trying to open the pipe (because the other end already closed it - or the other end might not be initialized any more).

Now my application is stuck waiting for the pipe to open. Because the processes are forked siblings that communicate with each other, I cannot be sure that process A has set up its end of the pipe before process B - i.e. I don't see a way to use `O_NONBLOCK` (not at least without continuously trying to set it up).

While reading from the pipe, the signals seem to abort it fine. It's just the opening of the pipe which locks up.

Any ideas?

Comment: Between forking and opening the pipe, refuse to shut down on termination?  Maybe even tell the other end you got a termination, and shut down cleanly?

Comment: I guess the main problem is that each process handles the signal on its own and therefore could close the connection before another process handled it. I can check if I was signalled before forking, but this still leaves a tiny time-window in which the signal could be raised and I still fork + open. I guess I can only try to use ``O_NONBLOCK`` while waiting for it to open (or a signal)...

Comment: Can you not open both ends of the fifo in the parent before forking? Then have each process close the descriptor it doesn't need after the fork.

Comment: Your single handlers, if you are post-fork, do not terminate.  Instead they set a flag saying "I should terminate".  Then you send a message over the pipe saying "I have been terminated".  If you get a message "I have been terminated" from the other end of the pipe, set the "I should terminate" flag and you respond back with "I have been terminated".  When you both "I should terminate" and have gotten a "I have been terminated" from the other end, you close the pipe.  (this assumes a 2-way communication channel)

Comment: I couldn't open both ends before forking because opening any end would be blocking if the other process is in the progress of terminating. I also do not have a 2-way communication and would have preferred to use signals for communicating the need to close.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I instead went with a nonblocking approach. I busy wait (with brief sleeps) until the pipe is established or termination is signalled.

Reading and writing works similarly. If no data is available (read 0 bytes), then I wait and retry. In case of an error I handle it, and, if not signalled, try again (because this needs to run in the background and not tear down the application).

It would have been quite hard to set up an additional communication channel just to sync the shutdown (plus handling that correctly).